# Are My Unity 2D Transform.Position Units Changing Between Builds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've put together a little Git repo to share with you some scripts from the Unity 2D platformer I've been working on. I have written some basic WASD movement control in the Movement.cs script (under Scripts/Character in the repo) and it is working really well. It does everything I need it to do, and while it is basic, I intend to polish it up a bit over the course of the development of the game. However, I've been noticing that every time I build the game, every moving entity moves at a faster speed. The "AI" (yes I use the term *very* loosely) that I programmed into enemies like the Chompas and BadBirds seems to be far too fast or far too slow, as are user-controlled movements and animated powerup bubbles.

Now, I believe I've traced it back to the way I create translations; I add vectors to Transform.Position whenever I need to move an object or entity. These vectors accept float values as their parameters, and seeing as I'm not entirely clear on what those values represent, I feel that may be where the issue lies. Are these distance values representative of some dynamic system of measurement that might be changing between builds? If so, how might I standardize my distances? Am I totally off the mark? Lol. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

To be perfectly clear, this issue occurs every time I hit play, regardless of whether or not changes have been made. Thanks again!

[Git repo](https://github.com/Lloyd7113/platformer.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try multiplying your movement by `Time.deltaTime`. 
If you don't do this (which it doesn't look like you are), then all your GameObjects will move at inconsistent speeds. The reason for this is that void Update() get's called once every frame, and the amount of frames that get drawn every second is variable (sometimes your game will run a little faster than at other times), and so your speed will be variable if you don't multiply it by `Time.deltaTime` (Time.deltaTime is the amount of time that has passed since the last frame, see the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html))
Another option is to use Unity's built in physics system with FixedUpdate(), which get's called at a fixed rate.
I would strongly recommend to follow online tutorials for how to make a platformer controller etc., such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGDeafTx5ug) one. Doing this will help teach you good practices and how to avoid common errors.